# Plot multiple variables in one histogram using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like below, it has 3 numeric variables which I would like to plot the frequency distribution of all 3 variables in one plot. I'm wondering if this is feasible without transforming the original dataset into, for example, long format? Thank you!

```
structure(list(v1 = c(0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1), v2 = c(0, 
0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1), v3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you want to use ggplot, then you'll need to reshape or do the tedious job of adding layers for each column.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. So I have no choice but transforming it...sigh

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer` makes quick work of it